# Ansible List of Dicts conversion issue

Tags: list, ansible, jinja2, vmware

i'm trying to variablise the deployments of VMs, I have two types of IP auto generated by IPAM and those that are manually assigned.

When running it through i constantly get the error msg`": "Elements value for option 'networks' is of type <class 'str'>` and we were unable to convert to dict: dictionary requested, could not parse JSON or key=value"

I'm struggling with how to get the data in the correct format for the vmware_guest module

my vars

---

```
vm_networks:
  - name: vlan_105
    ip: "auto"
    netmask: "auto"
    gateway: "auto"
    connected: true
    start_connected: true
    device_type: vmxnet3
  - name: vlan_106
    ip: "auto"
    netmask: "auto"
    gateway: "auto"
    connected: true
    start_connected: true
    device_type: vmxnet3
  - name: vlan_107
    ip: 192.168.0.1
    netmask: 255.255.255.0
    gateway: 192.168.0.254
    connected: true
    start_connected: true
```

my playbook outputs the following for the vm_networks after the IP addresses have been retrieved and added

```
   {
    "vm_networks_updated": [
        {
                "connected": true,
                "device_type": "vmxnet3",
                "gateway": "10.17.1.254",
                "ip": "10.17.1.2",
                "name": "vlan_105",
                "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
                "start_connected": true
            },
            {
                "connected": true,
                "device_type": "vmxnet3",
                "gateway": "10.19.4.254",
                "ip": "10.19.4.2",
                "name": "vlan_106",
                "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
                "start_connected": true
            },
            {
                "connected": true,
                "device_type": "vmxnet3",
                "gateway": "192.168.0.254",
                "ip": "192.168.0.1",
                "name": "vlan_107",
                "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
                "start_connected": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

my playbook after this is:

````
     var: vm_networks_updated

 - set_fact: 
     vm_networks_updated_keys: "{{ vm_networks_updated|     map(attribute='name')|map('community.general.dict_kv', 'name')|list }}"

 - debug:
     var: vm_networks_updated_keys

 - set_fact: 
     vm_networks_updated_dict: "{{ vm_networks_updated| zip(vm_networks_updated_keys) }}"

 - debug:
     var: vm_networks_updated_dict


 - name: Create a virtual machine from a template
   community.vmware.vmware_guest:
     hostname: "{{ vc_hostname }}"
     username: "{{ vc_username }}"
     password: "{{ vc_password }}"
     validate_certs: "{{ vc_validate_certs }}"
     template: "{{ vm_spec.template |default(vm_spec_template) }}"
     name: "{{ vm_spec.name }}"
     state: poweredon
     datacenter: "{{ vm_spec.datacenter }}"
     cluster: "{{ vm_spec.cluster }}"
     folder: "{{ vm_spec.folder }}"
     disk:
       - datastore: "{{ vm_spec.datastore }}"
         size_kb: "{{ vm_spec.disk_size * 1048576 }}"
         type: thin
     hardware:
       memory_mb: "{{ vm_spec.memory * 1048576 }}"
       num_cpus: "{{ vm_spec.cpus }}"
       num_cpu_cores_per_socket: "{{ vm_spec.cores_per_socket }}"
     networks: |
         "{{ vm_networks_updated_dict|to_yaml }}"
     wait_for_ip_address: true
     delegate_to: localhost
     register: deploy```

my output looks like:
 ```"vm_networks_updated_dict": [
     [
         {
             "connected": true,
             "device_type": "vmxnet3",
             "gateway": "10.17.1.254",
             "ip": "10.17.1.2",
             "name": "vlan_105",
             "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
             "start_connected": true
         },
         {
             "name": "vlan_105"
         }
     ],
     [
         {
             "connected": true,
             "device_type": "vmxnet3",
             "gateway": "10.19.4.254",
             "ip": "10.19.4.2",
             "name": "vlan_106",
             "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
             "start_connected": true
         },
         {
             "name": "vlan_106"
         }
     ],
     [
         {
             "connected": true,
             "device_type": "vmxnet3",
             "gateway": "192.168.0.254",
             "ip": "192.168.0.1",
             "name": "vlan_107",
             "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
             "start_connected": true
         },
         {
             "name": "vlan_107"
         }
     ]
 ]
}

TASK [deploy_vm : Create a virtual machine from a template]       ****************************************************************************************************   ****************************************************************************
task path: /root/ansible/roles/deploy_vm/tasks/vmguest.yml:18
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo    /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682354686.7525673-550065-107719873366957 `" && echo ansible-tmp-   1682354686.7525673-550065-107719873366957="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682354686.7525673-   550065-107719873366957 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file    /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vmware_guest.py
<localhost> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-54992960i4o82q/tmpzitqivth TO    /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682354686.7525673-550065-107719873366957/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682354686.7525673-550065-   107719873366957/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682354686.7525673-550065-107719873366957/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/libexec/platform-python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-   1682354686.7525673-550065-107719873366957/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682354686.7525673-550065-   107719873366957/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [bitwarden-001]: FAILED! => {
 "changed": false,
 "invocation": {
     "module_args": {
         "advanced_settings": [],
         "annotation": null,
         "cdrom": [],
         "cluster": "Bifrost",
         "convert": null,
         "customization": {
             "autologon": null,
             "autologoncount": null,
             "dns_servers": null,
             "dns_suffix": null,
             "domain": null,
             "domainadmin": null,
             "domainadminpassword": null,
             "existing_vm": null,
             "fullname": null,
             "hostname": null,
             "hwclockUTC": null,
             "joindomain": null,
             "joinworkgroup": null,
             "orgname": null,
             "password": null,
             "productid": null,
             "runonce": null,
             "script_text": null,
             "timezone": null
         },
         "customization_spec": null,
         "customvalues": [],
         "datacenter": "Asgard",
         "datastore": null,
         "delegate_to": "localhost",
         "delete_from_inventory": false,
         "disk": [
             {
                 "autoselect_datastore": null,
                 "controller_number": null,
                 "controller_type": null,
                 "datastore": "StarLord_Datastore01",
                 "disk_mode": null,
                 "filename": null,
                 "size": null,
                 "size_gb": null,
                 "size_kb": 10485760,
                 "size_mb": null,
                 "size_tb": null,
                 "type": "thin",
                 "unit_number": null
             }
         ],
         "esxi_hostname": null,
         "folder": "/testvms",
         "force": false,
         "guest_id": null,
         "hardware": {
             "boot_firmware": null,
             "cpu_limit": null,
             "cpu_reservation": null,
             "cpu_shares": null,
             "cpu_shares_level": null,
             "hotadd_cpu": null,
             "hotadd_memory": null,
             "hotremove_cpu": null,
             "iommu": null,
             "max_connections": null,
             "mem_limit": null,
             "mem_reservation": null,
             "mem_shares": null,
             "mem_shares_level": null,
             "memory_mb": 2097152,
             "memory_reservation_lock": null,
             "nested_virt": null,
             "num_cpu_cores_per_socket": 2,
             "num_cpus": 1,
             "scsi": null,
             "secure_boot": null,
             "version": null,
             "virt_based_security": null,
             "vpmc_enabled": null
         },
         "hostname": "",
         "is_template": false,
         "linked_clone": false,
         "name": "bitwarden-001",
         "name_match": "first",
         "networks": [],
         "nvdimm": {
             "label": null,
             "size_mb": 1024,
             "state": null
         },
         "password": "",
         "port": 443,
         "proxy_host": null,
         "proxy_port": null,
         "register": "deploy",
         "resource_pool": null,
         "snapshot_src": null,
         "state": "poweredon",
         "state_change_timeout": 0,
         "template": "oracle_linux_8.7_v0.1",
         "use_instance_uuid": false,
         "username": "",
         "uuid": null,
         "validate_certs": false,
         "vapp_properties": [],
         "wait_for_customization": false,
         "wait_for_customization_timeout": 3600,
         "wait_for_ip_address": true,
         "wait_for_ip_address_timeout": 300
     }
 },
 "msg": "Elements value for option 'networks' is of type <class 'str'> and we were unable to convert to dict: dictionary requested, could not parse JSON or key=value"```
````

Comment: > `networks: "{{ vm_networks_updated_dict }}"`, I'd guess.

Comment: Thanks .. i've been playing .. however this now give me error
"msg": "Elements value for option 'networks' is of type <class 'list'> and we were unable to convert to dict: <class 'list'> cannot be converted to a dict"

Comment: i don't really get what you are trying to do by attempting to transform to a dict (whiich is not the result you get anyway...), but the original data is already in the expected format according to the documentation and your output => `networks: "{{ vm_networks_updated }}"`

Comment: thanks all for your help .. i think i went down the rabbit hole with this one.. and then carried on even trying to fix the data structure even though the error was introduced during testing .. the data returned originally by vm_networks_updated was sufficient .. the later data transforms weren't needed ie vm_networks_updated_dict

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using template and lookup .. ie

tasks:

```
- name: generate network template format 
  template:
    src: networks.j2
    dest: "{{ template }}"

- name: Create a virtual machine from a template
  community.vmware.vmware_guest:
    hostname: "{{ vc_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vc_username }}"
    password: "{{ vc_password }}"
    validate_certs: "{{ vc_validate_certs }}"
    template: "{{ vm_spec.template |default(vm_spec_template) }}"
    name: "{{ vm_spec.name }}"
    state: poweredon
    datacenter: "{{ vm_spec.datacenter }}"
    cluster: "{{ vm_spec.cluster }}"
    folder: "{{ vm_spec.folder }}"
    disk:
      - datastore: "{{ vm_spec.datastore }}"
        size_kb: "{{ vm_spec.disk_size * 1048576 }}"
        type: thin
    hardware:
      memory_mb: "{{ vm_spec.memory * 1048576 }}"
      num_cpus: "{{ vm_spec.cpus }}"
      num_cpu_cores_per_socket: "{{ vm_spec.cores_per_socket }}"
    networks: "{{ lookup('file', template) | from_yaml }}"
    wait_for_ip_address: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: deploy
```

and template:

```
{% for network in vm_networks_updated %}
- name: {{ network.name }}
{% for key, value in network.items() %}{% if key != 'name' %}
  {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: note {{ template }} is just a path and filename to read and write from

Comment: That's really a lot of hard work to spit out the exact same data structure as `vm_networks_updated`.